# Using glDrawRangeElements in OpenGL 2.1

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Based on the information in [Questions about glDrawRangeElements()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549991/questions-about-gldrawrangeelements) and given the following items:

```
struct MyVertex
{
   GLfloat x, y, z;        //Vertex
};

const GLushort pindices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4 };

struct MyVertex pvertex[6];
//VERTEX 0
pvertex[0].x = 0.0;
pvertex[0].y = 0.0;
pvertex[0].z = 0.0;
//VERTEX 1
pvertex[1].x = 1.0;
pvertex[1].y = 0.0;
pvertex[1].z = 0.0;
//VERTEX 2
pvertex[2].x = 0.0;
pvertex[2].y = 1.0;
pvertex[2].z = 0.0;
//VERTEX 3
pvertex[3].x = 0.0;
pvertex[3].y = 0.0;
pvertex[3].z = 0.0;
//VERTEX 4
pvertex[4].x = 1.0;
pvertex[4].y = 0.0;
pvertex[4].z = 0.0;
//VERTEX 5
pvertex[5].x = 0.0;
pvertex[5].y = -1.0;
pvertex[5].z = 0.0;
```

and the following initialization:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexVBOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(struct MyVertex)*3, &pvertex[0].x, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(struct MyVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glGenBuffers(1, &IndexVBOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*3, pindices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

the following calls:

```
glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*) pindices);
glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 5, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*) pindices+3);
```

should draw two triangles. However, I get an EXE_BAD_ACCESS. If I use pindices[0] in glDrawRangeElements; I get the triangle defined by the first three indices. Using pindices[3] in the second call to glDrawRangeElements doesn't result in anything being drawn and I don't get any OpenGl errors. At no time does the second glDrawRangeElements call draw the inverted triangle defined by the final three vertices. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental regarding the use of pointers here, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you've read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are not directly related to `glDrawRangeElements`, but to incorrect use of VBOs.

First of all, when using VBOs (or more precise, when binding a VBO to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), the index pointer argument to `glDraw...` is interpreted as a byte offset into the buffer bound to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point (the index buffer), similar to how the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` affects the array argument to `glVertexPointer`. Therefore the bad access. So replace `(const GLvoid*)pindices` with `0` in the first `glDrawRangeElements` call. The second call is wrong anyway, as you cannot do pointer arithmetic on a void pointer (it shouldn't even compile, what size should it be increased by? bytes? shorts?). So in the second call use `(const GLushort*)0+3` to gain a byte offset to the 4th index in the index buffer.

Second, your buffers only contain half of the needed data, as you use `sizeof(...)*3` in both `glBufferData` calls but your arrays actually contain 6 elements.