# Is it valid to cast integer to GLvoid* in C++20 using bit_cast?

Tags: c++, opengl, casting, c++20

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23177229/9723177) has asked for how to cast between integer types and `GLvoid*` in C++11 (based on the tags for that question) but here I'm interested in C++20.

Now that there is `std::bit_cast` as an option for doing type conversion, I'm wondering if it would be the "correct" way to use integers with OpenGL functions that for historical reasons take a `GLvoid*` to represent a byte offset (e.g. [glDrawRangeElements](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glDrawRangeElements.xhtml)), or whether the methods referenced at the previous question should be used instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bit_cast` is definitely the wrong thing here. `void*` is not required to be the same size as most integer types. `bit_cast` *requires* that the source and destination types have the exact same size. Therefore, on 32-bit systems, a `std::bit_cast<void*>(24ull)` is a compile error. While on 64-bit systems, a simple `std::bit_cast<void*>(24)` is a compile error.

And not even `uintptr_t` is required to have the same size as a pointer; only that it has *at least* as many bits as a pointer. If it has more, then `bit_cast` will choke on it.

Just do a `reinterpret_cast<void*>`, if you don't feel like using a C-style cast.

Answer (score 4):

No, although (with an appropriately-sized integer) it will often work in practice, and none of this is strictly-conforming anyway.  This is a C API, so it means `(void*)offset` (in C).  If your toolchain has the expected C compatibility), you can write that in C++, in which case it’s equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<void*>(offset)`, but not necessarily to `bit_cast<void*>(offset)` (which preserves the bit pattern even if `reinterpret_cast` doesn’t and additionally requires that `sizeof offset==sizeof(void*)`).