# What is the right type of C++ cast here?

Tags: c++, opengl, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I like/hate linters so I figured I'd try `clang-tidy` with all the checks turned on and see how I'm doing and how I can improve. Aside from stylistic or non-applicable rules, I hit this call:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
```

which triggers `C-style casts are discouraged; use static_cast/const_cast/reinterpret_cast [google-readability-casting]` so I fixed it with a `static_cast<void *>(nullptr)` with the `nullptr` for good measure. Then I naively "fixed" the next one:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), static_cast<void *>(3 * sizeof(float)));
```

which is an actual error because you can't cast an `unsigned long` to `void *`. Fair enough, my bad. I figured an `unsigned long` was a good candidate for a `reinterpret_cast`, and so I did, and it compiled fine and ran fine, except that C++ Core Guidelines say `do not use reinterpret_cast [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-reinterpret-cast]`.

Short of `dynamic_cast`, which is a bit silly here, what are my options here?

Comment: `3 * sizeof(float)` is an integer (type `size_t`), why do you want to cast it to a pointer?

Comment: Because the function needs a `const void *` as a parameter: `void glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, const void * pointer)`.

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), nullptr);` should be fine. I don't see a reason for a cast.

Comment: @mch so, in your opinion, `nullptr` is equivalent to `3 * sizeof(float)`?

Comment: You should use the reinterpret_cast as mentioned in anonther topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679610/how-to-cast-an-integer-to-a-void-without-violating-c-core-guidelines
The guidelines are not a law but as said a guideline. Guidelines don't always apply to each circumstance.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Yes thank you, that answers my question.